# "Disable" SSR in nextjs

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to create a Browser-Application without SSR, with React and MUI. So I found a NextJS-Template here:

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs-with-typescript

I want to disable SSR completely, let's say in the best case starting with _document.tsx, but at least the file _app.tsx and all following as for example _index.tsx should be rendered without SSR.

So, how to disable SSR "completely"?

Comment: The sole purpose of Next is to use SSR, if you don't want it, just drop it entirely and use normal react alone.

Comment: My friend, you are using the wrong tool for the job. Look towards CRA(Create react app)

Comment: Next.js [pre-renders every page](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering), either at build time when using SSG, or at request time when using SSR. You can't have client-side rendering _only_, you have to have it along with SSG or SSR. What is the use case for wanting to disable SSR? You may not need to disable SSR entirely, but just for a specific piece of code?

Comment: Yeah... thanks. I am back to plain react. I had too many problems integrating react packages into next... starting with PouchDB...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove the **getStaticProps**, **getStaticPaths** and **getServerSideProps** from the pages you don't want to SSR and it will act like a normal react page.

Comment: That is strange... there is none of those functions... I still get errors from pouchdb, which can be explained by "active SSR" :-/

Answer (score 6):

While some might tell you to use plain React, others still use Next.js because of things like file-based routing, sane ESLint and TypeScript defaults, and fast compilation times (because of [SWC](https://swc.rs/)). If you prefer the developer experience of Next.js over standalone React, but don't want/need SSR, then you have the option to use a [static HTML export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export):

> `next export` allows you to export your Next.js application to static HTML, which can be run standalone without the need of a Node.js server. It is recommended to only use `next export` if you don't need any of the [unsupported features](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features) requiring a server.

The example template you linked to shouldn't need any additional code changes (running `next export` on it worked fine for me, it only threw a warning about a missing ESLint configuration which is [easy to set up](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint)).

Comment: I am in the verge of doing so (plain react)... I am using nextjs because of curiosity :-)

Currently I am in _app.tsx and shutting down SSR "manually": By dynamic() - import and if (typeof window !== "undefined")... That seems to work... And with that static export is also working.

Comment: instead of disabling we can try using React.lazy() ,

Answer (score 0):

For those who struggle with this, if you want to disable SSR (Server-Side Rendering) in your page's router in Next.js, you can dynamically import the layout in _app.jsx or _app.tsx like so:

```ts
    // _app.tsx
    import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
    import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
    
    // Dynamically import the Layout component with SSR disabled
    const Layout = dynamic(() => import('@/components/app/layouts/default'), { ssr: false });
    
    export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
      return (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      );
    }
```

Note: Make sure to replace '@/components/app/layouts/default' with the correct path to your layout component.